Why does iterating break up my text file lines while a generator doesn't?
For each line of a text file I want to do heavy calculations. The amount of lines can be millions so I'm using multiprocessing:
num_workers = 1
with open(my_file, 'r') as f:
    with multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool(num_workers) as pool:    
        for data in pool.imap(my_func, f, 100):
            print(data)

I'm testing interactively hence ThreadPool() (will be replaced in final version). For map or imap documentation says:

This method chops the iterable into a number of chunks which it submits to the process pool as separate tasks

Since my opened file is an iterable (each iteration is a line) I expect this to work but it breaks up lines in the middle. I made a generator that returns lines as expected, but I want to understand why the generator is needed at all. Why isn't the chunking happening on line boundaries?
UPDATE:
to clarify if I use this generator:
def chunked_reader(file, chunk_size=100):
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        chunk = []
        i = 0
        for line in f:            
            if i == chunk_size:
                yield chunk
                chunk = []
                i = 0
            i += 1            
            chunk.append(line)
    # yield final chunk
    yield chunk

the calculation works, returns expected values. If I use the file object directly, I get errors somehow indicating the chunking is not splitting on line boundaries.
UPDATE 2:
it's chunking the line into each individual character and not line by line. I can also take another environment with python 3.9 and that has the same behavior. So it has been like this for some time and seems to be "as designed" but not very intuitive.
UPDATE 3:
To clarify on the marked solution, my misunderstanding was that chunk_size will send a list of data to process to my_func. Internally my_func iterates over the passed in data. But since my assumption wrong and each line gets send separately to my_func regardless of chunk_size, the internal iteration was iterating over the string, not as I expected list of strings.

num_workers will be invoked for each element of f, which will be a line. Your problem cannot be reproduced by me. Have you found a bug in Python? What is your platform and Python version?

It's Python 3.12.4 on Windows

you think the function is called with a chunk as input so you are iterating over the input inside my_func. It is not. It is always called with a single line, or a single element of the iterable, Hence my answer ...

OK, finally got it and that explains why the issue happens as the my_func itself iterates internally and in this case over the string.  How about performance? I will have to check as I feel sending each line separately to a process will be inefficient?

My understanding is that if you are using multithreading (ThreadPool) then the internal input and output queues are instances of queue.SimpleQueue rather than multiprocessing.queues.SimpleQueue and the chunksize value becomes less important. With multiprocessing it is better to do fewer, albeit larger, get and put operations to these queues and thus you should use explicit chunking when using imap with large iterables (the map method will compute a default chunksize if None is specified).

Try to make each chunk large enough that the worker will take at least a few haundred milliseconds per chunk, or just try 1,10,100,1000 untill you see no improvement in the number of tasks done per second, you will never find one optimal number anyway.

When calling map with chunksize=None specified, map will convert the passed iterable to a list if necessary to get its length (iterable_size) and then compute chunksize, remainder = divmod(iterable_size, 4 * pool_size) . Then if remainder: chunksize += 1. If using imap with multiprocessing, I would approximate the iterable size and use this same calculation for your chunksize argument. Essentially, each pool process will process approximately 4 large chunks. If you are doing multithreading, see if chunking makes much of a difference.

imap chunking is an implementation detail, your function will be called with a single element of the iterable regardless of the chunk size.
for line in file:
    result = my_func(line)

Becomes
for result in pool.imap(my_func, file, some_chunk_size):
    pass

It is syntactically the same as builtins.map without the chunk size, but people don't really use it either.
The chunking size controls how many elements are packed in a list before being pickled and sent over a pipe, the chunking process is transparent to your code, your function wil always be called with a single line regardless of the chunk size, you should play around with the chunk size and see if it improves performance in your case.
Note that imap interally has a for loop, so it should work exactly like a simple for loop on the iterated object.

It is syntactically the same as map but people don't really use it either. This is just so wrong. People certainly do use it and there is a huge difference between map and imap. First, map takes its iterable argument (file in this case) and if it is not a list it will convert it to a list as if you specified pool.map(my_func, list(file). So there can be a large difference related to memory usage. Second, with map you get no results until all results are returned as a list. With imap you can iterate the results as they are returned by the worker function my_func.

With imap and imap_unordered, since in general it does not know the size of the iterable without converting it to a list, it uses a default chunksize of 1. For rmultiprocessing in particular dealing with large iterablles, you should specify the chunksize.

@Booboo i have builtins.map linked, not pool.map ... i should make it more explicit in the text.

Nevertheless,there is a huge difference between multiprocessing.pool.Pool.imap and mutlirpcoessing.pool.Pool.map. Why would you want to compare imap with the built-in map? And people do use the built-in map.

Chunking is not as important for multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool because the overhead of putting tasks to the internal task queue is not as great as for the multiprocessing case where it is better to do larger but fewer puts.
